# CSS/Tailwind using flex or grid to display looped data in 3 rows

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have a small school project where I try to learn using CSS and Tailwind. I need to show my data using a loop in Vue. This data needs to be shown in rows of 3, 2 and 3 in desktop view and all underneath each other in mobile view. When in desktop view it is necessary that all items are the same size and the items of the second row should be centered. I don't know what is the best way to display all items like the image below:

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not purely with Tailwind I believe although its growing so much lately who knows, it might be possible.

The layout is straightforward except for the middle row. For that I added extra margins to force just 2 items on that row, and that would be where your custom css would come in and target those items using `:nth-child()`

https://codepen.io/clintongreen/pen/gOwmEKY